# как назначить tablespace уже созданному пользователю?

Tags: sql, oracle

Нигде в интернете не нашел этой информации, только информацию где при создании назначают табличное пространство, а если я уже создал ?

Comment: `alter user myuser default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp;`. А вы по каким ключевым словам искали?

Answer (score 1):

воспользуйтесь [ALTER USER ...](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4003.htm):

```
ALTER USER user_name DEFAULT TABLESPACE tbs_name QUOTA UNLIMITED ON tbs_name;
```